# JQuery change function cause full page postback when using masterpage and updatepanel?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages

```
$('#bn1').click(function () {
    $('#textbox1').change();
})

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up123" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <div style="margin-top: 250px;">
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox1" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="DateTimePicker" />
         <asp:Button runat="server" ID="bn1" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="clickme" />
      </div>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

when using the above function with masterpage in my content page, it cause full page postback instead partial postback
if i use this without masterpage, it's perfectly fine, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Put `return false` to stop the server-side click event from happening, like this:

```
$('#bn1').click(function () {
    $('#textbox1').change();

    // This stops the server control from doing a click, which 
    // posts the form back to the server
    return false;
});
```

---

UPDATE:

To verify which control is actually causing the post back to the server, do this in your `Page_Load` event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var controlIdThatCausedPostBack = String.Empty;
    var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);

    if (scriptManager != null)
    {
        var smUniqueId = scriptManager.UniqueID;
        var smFieldValue = Request.Form[smUniqueId];

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(smFieldValue) && smFieldValue.Contains("|"))
        {
            controlIdThatCausedPostBack= smFieldValue.Split('|')[1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        controlIdThatCausedPostBack = Page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
    }

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(updatePanelControlIdThatCausedPostBack))
    {
        // Here we have the control ID that causes the post back

    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, it still causing the full page postback, tks for the reply thou.

Comment: again, if i dont use master page, everything works for, the button triggers the partial postback

Comment: @JoeLu - Are you sure it is the button, because your `TextBox` server control has `AutoPostBack="True"`, which means when it loses focus it will post back to the server?

Comment: @JoeLu - I have updated my answer to include the logic in `Page_Load` that will tell you which control actually caused the post back to the server.

Comment: sorry about the unclear question, it's actually caused by the jquery function change()

Comment: basically the change() function will cause the full page postback when using masterpage, even the textbox control is inside the updatepanel

Comment: @JoeLu - have you tried removing the `AutoPostBack="True"` from the `TextBox` markup?

Comment: the purpose is to fire the textchanged even for the textbox, if i remove that, the event won't fire :( my goal is actually to use some jquery functions to change the textbox text, then fire up some .net functions at code behind when textchanged event fired

Comment: @JoeLu - what will the .NET functions do? Will any of them need to interact with the page server controls or no?

Comment: nope, currently my test page only try to update the label control text once, here's the brief Label1.Text = Now , that's the only line under textchanged event